# Item level and blacksmith crafting materials?

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I find items with the right level to salvage particular ingredients?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/68909/how-do-i-find-items-with-the-right-level-to-salvage-particular-ingredients)

my question is about getting crafting materials from items. I understand that the crafting materials you get depend on the level of the item, but does anyone have the level ranges or drop rate?

For example:

**1-20 - Normal
21-40 - Nightmare
41-60 - Hell
61-63 - Inferno**

Please note that the values above are just to explain, I made them up. What I mean is, if an item has a level of 5 it always give Normal crafting materials, etc.

Also, what are the drop rates on the crafting materials? I noticed that when I salvage Inferno blues I sometimes get an **Iridescent Tear** along with the **Exquisite Essence**, but sometimes just the **Exquisite Essence**. When salvaging rares, I always get both.

As a closing off point, is it possible to get **Fiery Brimstone** from non-legendary items?

**Edit:** Just in case someone is interested in this topic, I spent all day researching and wrote a [post](http://easydiablo3.com/post/2012/08/30/Diablo-3-Blacksmith-Guide.aspx) on my blog. As per the rules, **THIS IS MY BLOG**.

Comment: For your chance to get certain salvage materials: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/66138/20456

Comment: You're using my hard work there, and you're not giving me credit for it.  I really don't like that.

Comment: The only thing I took was the level ranges. Anyway I gave you credit now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the level ranges, check [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/68909/how-do-i-find-items-with-the-right-level-to-salvage-particular-ingredients) question and the great answer there.

As you noticed, magic items always give magic materials, rares always give magic+rare, and *inferno* legendaries will always give rare+Fiery Brimstone. In addition, magic items have a **15%** chance to give rare materials. ([Source](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/amulet-1PQswa))

It is possible to get Fiery Brimstone from non-legendary inferno tier items, but the drop rate is **~0.1%** for rares, and even less for magic items.

Comment: So as far as I understand it, armor and weapons from level 60 - 63 always give Inferno, but the level range for rings, amulets, and follower relics is 59+.

The only problem I have with this theory is that sometimes level 60 items give Hell mats.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Note that the level in question is the required level, and not the item level (which wasn't even shown on items earlier).

Comment: What about the fact that level 60 items sometimes give Hell materials?

Comment: @TheGateKeeper which type and quality items? I'm not sure I've experienced that.

Comment: I salved some Magic level 60 items and they seen to have a chance to give both Hell or Inferno mats. Also, looking on the armory (http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/amulet-1PQswa) it seems the % for Magic items to give rare mats is 15% and not 5%.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I've updated accordingly. Are you sure you're looking at the _required_ level and not the item level?

Comment: What do you mean? Items of iLvl 60 also have a level requirement of 60.

Comment: They don't, actually. The required level is usually a bit lower than the item level. Check that amulet you linked, or other items in the armory/in-game.

Comment: I see what you mean. So for armor and equipment, they need to be iLvl 60-63 and have a required level of 60+, while amulets need to be 60-63 and have a requirement level of 59+.

Comment: I was under the wrong impression that items with a required level of 6 can be iLvl 60. I understand it now.