# What does the difficulty level on a crafting material mean?

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I find items with the right level to salvage particular ingredients?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/68909/how-do-i-find-items-with-the-right-level-to-salvage-particular-ingredients)

I'm playing Nightmare Act III and I just salvaged an item, I don't remember what it was though.

I put the crafting materials I got from it in my stash but I noticed I didn't have any of this type yet. The weird thing is that the type of crafting material I received is marked Hell instead of Nightmare.

Is this a bug? What does the *difficulty property* of a crafting material depend on?

Comment: this question has what you want: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66134/how-do-i-get-more-rare-crafting-ingredients

Comment: And I just updated it again, to make sure it should answer what you need to know.

Answer (score -2):

That label is just telling you the origin where it drops (the difficulty level where you find the items that can be salvaged into these parts).

Comment: No, it doesn't.  You can gather Hell materials from both Nightmare, AND Inferno difficulties.  The difficulty you play on plays a role only in the fact of the level range of items it can drop.

Comment: It's just a rough estimate, because of the item levels dropping. This might be even more serious after 1.05 (haven't played a lot since then), but in general it's the rough association, similar to how you can find a more powerful series of act 1 items starting in act 4 normal/act 1 nightmare.

Comment: its still possible to find hell stuff on inferno levels.  Rare, but still possible.